# Video-Player controls doesnt stick to the video

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm using nativescript-videoplayer plugin it works fine. However, when i press on the controls to pause or skip the video then scroll down the controls floats as am scrolling

i tried exposing "hideMediaControls" and calling it on scroll, gross

```
<GridLayout *ngIf="selectedTabview == 0" row="2" width="100%"
    backgroundColor="white">
    <ListView #listview [items]="items" separatorColor="transparent">
            <ng-template let-item="item">
                    <StackLayout >
                            <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto" columns="64, *"
                        class="post-content">
                         <Image row="0" col="0" rowSpan="2" src="~/app/images/br.jpg"
                             stretch="aspectFill" class="postImageSmall" loadMode="async"></Image>
                             <Label row="0" col="1" class="postAuthorName" [text]="item.name"></Label>
                             <Label row="1" col="1" class="postDateSmall" [text]="item.price"></Label>
                           <WrapLayout  row="2" col="0" colSpan="2">
                             <Label class="postTitle" textWrap="true"
                                 [text]="item.categor"></Label> 
                                 <VideoPlayer row="2" col="0" colSpan="2" height="380" stretch="aspectFill"
                                 src="https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
                                 autoplay="true" controls="true" fill="true"></VideoPlayer>
                </WrapLayout>
                </GridLayout>
           </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

No errors 
I expect Videoplayer controls to stick to the video

[And here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Dor.jpg)

Comment: Can you show your entire layout and possibly a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: @Manoj i edited my question with the details you asked for which are the layout and a screenshot of the issue feel free to check it